# How to find last modified rows or records in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-update, primary-key

I have an employee table with their general information. I don't have a modified date column. I cannot add any more columns.

How do I find the last modified records?

Comment: You can not! No such info is available for records.

Comment: What is your DBMS? What exactly does "last modified records" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the last time table was updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489469/find-the-last-time-table-was-updated)

Answer (score -1):

If there is a DateModified column, or something like that, and you want the 10 most recent rows (for example) you could use a query like:

```
SELECT Top 10 * FROM myTable ORDER BY DateModified DESC;
```

You don't specify the flavor of SQL, so that query might be somewhat different if you're in Oracle, SQL Server, or MS Access.

If you don't have a column like that, and you want to know the most recently *added* records, if the primary key is an autoincrementing number, you could do the same thing, but sort by PrimaryKey descending. If you truly want *modified* (i.e., updated) records, and you don't have a DateModified column, you're out of luck. There's no way to know.

Comment: i dont have modified date column

Comment: DOes inserting a new column called modifed date will  work

Answer (score -1):

Use MAX Aggregate function :

```
SELECT MAX(Modifieddate)
FROM your_table
WHERE your_conditions.
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this Code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Update_Table UT1
WHERE UT1.Modified_Date = (SELECT MAX(UT2.Modified_Date) 
FROM Update_Table UT2 
WHERE UT2.PK = UT1.PK
AND UT2.Last_User = user)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to get the last updated time.

```
select top 1 a.object_id, b.name, a.last_user_update from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats as a, sys.objects as b where a.object_id=b.object_id and b.name = 'your_table_name' order by last_user_update desc
```