# How do I make a trigger in SQL to fire an event in C# dot net?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I don't want to complicate by giving all details of actual reason for this requirement. Hence, I'll try to give a simple example.

Following is my requirement:
1) Pop out a MessageBox whenever there is a change of value in a table called stock.
2) In simple words, if I run following query in MS SQL:

```
update stocktable set stockcount = 4 where StockID = 1111
```

Then, my application should recognize that there is a change in value so it should give me a popup in MessageBox in my application.

## I HAVE ALREADY TRIED THE FOLLOWING:

I have been able to achieve this by checking stockcount every second using a timer.
But it's not feasible in terms of performance. Because if say there are 500 users, then on all 500 computers, there will be 500(people) * 12(hours) * 60(minues) * 60(minues) per day. 
Hence, the other way I could think of is to invoke function to display MessageBox only when there is a change rather than checking for the change from application every second.
Please help. I am writing this code in Visual Studio using C#. Back-end is MSSQL.

Comment: Read about [`SqlDependency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You definitely don't want to be thinking about a trigger - triggers should be *fast* and *local* (ideally not trying to access any resources outside of their own database)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for that suggestion. But if not trigger, then what could possibly solve this problem?

Comment: Zohar's offered one suggestion.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for your suggestion. The article looks like possible solution. I'll implement and test it and update on this post if it works. Really appreciate your input.

Comment: My suggestion is try to avoid using Triggers, they are error prompt and are not very efficient when data gets big. If you can try to find different solution for your problem.

Comment: @LyubomirDimov Thank you for your comment. I am considering Zorhar's suggestion of implementing SQLDEPENDENCY. Testing it right now :)

Answer (score 0):

you are interested in what value is changed?
If not you can try something like.. 
[Find the last time table was updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489469/find-the-last-time-table-was-updated)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am not looking for what is mentioned in this article. I precisely need the new value and display it on the MessageBox.