# Table Details in Azure Datawarehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Is there any in-built query/catalog view available in **Azure Data warehouse** to show last updated date, last
inserted date, last deleted date, last index scanned date of a table? I tried below query

```
SELECT
tbl.name
,ius.last_user_update
,ius.user_updates
,ius.last_user_seek
,ius.last_user_scan
,ius.last_user_lookup
,ius.user_seeks
,ius.user_scans
,ius.user_lookups
FROM
sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_index_usage_stats ius INNER JOIN
sys.tables tbl ON (tbl.OBJECT_ID = ius.OBJECT_ID)
WHERE ius.database_id = DB_ID()
```

But it is not giving output against all the tables. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` instead of `sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_index_usage_stats` in your query and it will work fine.

I'm getting the required output:

[image]

If you want to find out when was the last table updated, you can query dynamic management view (DMV) – `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` and easily figure out when was the table updated last, try the below query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
 last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( '<database_name>')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('<table_name>')
```

**Change `<database_name>` and `<table_name>` with your values.**

Comment: sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats  is not supported in Azure Datawarehouse

Comment: ohh. I request you to remove 'sql-server' and 'azure-sql-database' tags from the thread and add 'azure-sql-data-warehouse' tag to target the right audience. Meanwhile, I'll try to provide required solution.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find for Azure Synapse Data warehouse was this query. Only lets you know when last the schema changed (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489501)):

```
SELECT name, [modify_date] FROM sys.tables
where name like '%YOUR-TABLE-NAME%'
```